# heatmap in R, duplicate names in rows

Tags: r, heatmap

I am programming a heatmap in R based on a csv file. This contains the following information:

```
NAME,metformin,metformin,phenformin,phenyl biguanide,metformin,estradiol
Adenocarcinoma of lung,0,0,0,-1.834006462,1.715939688,0
Adenocarcinoma of lung,1.995916353,0,0,0,0,0
Thymic carcinoma,1.154056722,1.106488961,0,1.145126548,0,-1.14095315
alpha-1-Antitrypsin deficiency,0,0,0,0,-1.917025669,-1.974151858
```

So I want to create a heatmap in which in the name of the rows appears the labels: Adenocarcinoma of the lung, Adenocarcinoma... etc. I am doing this steps:

```
hm<-read.csv("heatmap1.csv",sep=",")
row.names(hm)<-hm$NAME
hm<-hm[,2:7]
hm_matrix<-data.matrix(hm)
heatM<-heatmap(hm_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = cm.colors(256), scale="column", margins=c(5,10))
```

The problem I got is in the line that says:

```
row.names(hm)<-hm$NAME

Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 2L)) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

I know that I have a duplicated name, but I really need that data appears in the heatmap because the measure levels (the quantities) are different even if they are from the same disease.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  `make.unique` to make unique versions of the names

```
row.names(hm) <-  make.unique(as.character(hm$NAME))
```

Comment: thanks @mnel, actually I was pasting the row.names, that are numerical and not duplicates, with the NAME field. It worked, but your solutions is better :)